# Tab functionality using toggle buttons

Tags: android

### I have achieved dynamic display of contentents below tab using tabhost

---

- But how to achieve the same using a set of toggle buttons

**I have code the xml part .... but having ambiguity in implementing Java part of the code**

***Use case is :*** if i click one toggle button a layout from one activity must display below in fragment area ..... if i click other so on...

same as it happens in tabhost .... here using togglebuttons

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  
    <include layout="@layout/toggle_set_for_tabs" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10" >
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**toggle_set_for_tabs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**outputxml**

[image]

Any ideas on how to implement the feature

Answer (score 1):

Using RadioButton would be a better idea.

- Here is the radio buttons in xml that would behave like tabs:

  ```
      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/rdb1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:button="@null"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="Tab1"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/rdb2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:button="@null"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="Tab2"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/rdb3"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.34"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:button="@null"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="Tab3
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
         </RadioGroup>
  ```

  - Register onclick method in your java code.

  @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

  ```
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.rdb1:

          if (rdb1.isChecked()) {
              // load fragment 1
          }
          break;

      case R.id.rdb2:

          if (rdb2.isChecked()) {
                          // load fragment 2
          }

          break;

      case R.id.rdb3:

          if (rdb3.isChecked()) {
                          // load fragment 3
          }

          break;


      default:
                          // default fragment
          break;
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks ... hey can u put the complete code of java .... it will help me to understand better ..... which activity should i need to extend ... i am a new bie